# pkgutil doesn't show Xcode Command Line Tools after upgrade to macOS 11.3

Tags: command-line, install, xcode

I've upgraded to macOS 11.3 from macOS 11.2.3. I'd installed Xcode Command Line Tools using Homebrew. Before the upgrade, I used pkgutil to check if Xcode CLT was installed and I got

```
% /usr/sbin/pkgutil --packages | grep CL
com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables
% /usr/sbin/pkgutil --pkg-info com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables
package-id: com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables
```

After the upgrade from macOS 11.2.3 to macOS 11.3, Command Line Tools is installed and usable. However, I didn't see the same results when using pkgutil to check if Xcode CLT was installed.

```
% xcode-select --version
xcode-select version 2384.
% xcode-select -p
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
% ls -l /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  5 root  wheel  160 Jan  9 07:43 Library
drwxr-xr-x  6 root  wheel  192 Apr 27 23:15 SDKs
drwxr-xr-x  7 root  wheel  224 Apr 24 16:19 usr
% brew doctor
Your system is ready to brew.
% /usr/sbin/pkgutil --packages | grep CL
% /usr/sbin/pkgutil --pkg-info com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables
No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.
```

Is it still possible to use pkgutil to check if Xcode CLT is installed? Has the package name or location changed?

Comment: Big Sur removes parts if not all of the CLT when installed or upgraded.  You should re-install the CLT after any update you apply to Big Sur.